# How to save the ssh commands history to a file

Tags: ssh, history

I'm going to allow a server administrator freelancer to access my server to do some tasks for me, so I want to save all the SSH commands that will be used in a file so I can access this file later and make sure that he didn't execute any malicious commands on my server.

I don't want the commands in this file to be deleted with the command (history -c), and also not to be deleted by ending the session.

Comment: What would be the point? If you give this person root access, they can undo anything you do and can find ways of getting around it. If you do not trust this person, you cannot really do anything about it.

Comment: in place where auditing is mandatory, what your looking for is setup by a relay host, in which temporary admin have no privilege. he will `sudo ssh target_host` , sudo will log all to a file. You can also have a look at things like cyberark.

Comment: If you cannot afford a solution based on a relay host (@Archemar's idea above) then a similar local "ssh keylogger" started from `authorized_keys` would be acceptable. See [this answer](https://superuser.com/a/679433/669855)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hi in order to do so (and even know who is doing any command as root with sudo) you can add in /etc/rsyslog.conf `local6.*               /var/log/commands.log` then restart syslog service (it will add a logger called local6) and add in /etc/bashrc the following `export PROMPT_COMMAND='RETRN_VAL=$?;logger -p local6.debug "$(whoami) [$$]: $(history 1 | sed "s/^[ ]*[0-9]\+[ ]*//" ) [$RETRN_VAL]"'` which will call syslog service local6 to log the last line of history with the two users when sudo is used

Comment: That will only work if the user doesn't also set the PROMPT_COMMAND in their local files. Also, you probably want to add this to `/etc/profile` so you don't need to assume that the OP's machine has been set up to have `/etc/profile` source `/etc/bash.bashrc`, given that presumably we will be dealing with login shells.

Comment: @terdon There are many ways to escape this and I don't think there is a bulletproof solution to the OP's problem. This one is a good-enough solution, though.

Comment: Oh it is indeed, @xhienne, and more than good enough! However, it does rely on having `/etc/bash.bashrc` sourced by `/etc/profile` and, as far as I know, that isn't standard, so I thought it worth mentioning. To be honest I think the whole thing is pointless since if this contractor has root access, they can do anything they want, but this is probably as close as the OP can get to a working solution.